# Phaser.js Block Not stacking on top of each other

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework, phaserjs

Phaser.js Block Not stacking on top of each other,

I am trying to stacking block on top of each other but cant able to do it, block goes inside another block.
It working fine for two block, but if i increase the amount of block it not work.

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 320,
    height: 640,
    physics: {
        default: "arcade",
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 },
            debug: true,
        },
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,
    },
};
var platform, blockGroup;
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
    this.load.image("ground", "assets/platform.png");
    this.load.image("block", "assets/block.png");
}

function create() {
    platform = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    platform.create(400, 610, "ground").setScale(2).refreshBody();

    const blockGroup = this.physics.add.group(); // Enable physics for the group

    const blockSize = 50; // Adjust the block size as needed
    const blockCount = 5;

    for (let i = 0; i < blockCount; i++) {
        const block = this.physics.add.sprite(100, i * 100, "block");
        block.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        block.setBounce(0);
        block.displayWidth = blockSize;
        block.displayHeight = blockSize;
        blockGroup.add(block);
    }

    this.physics.add.collider(blockGroup);
    this.physics.add.collider(blockGroup, platform);
}

function update() {}
```

[image]

I am using phaser@3.60.0

Comment: Was my answer helpful, or do you need some more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on [this post](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/adding-colliders-to-stack-of-block/5378/2?u=akumagamo) it seems, that acrade physics seem to be *"unstable"* and you would have to use the property `customSeparateY` or `customSeparateX` on the group elements and "program" the collision in the `collider` callback function.
[link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body-customSeparateY)

Here is the [offical example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics/arcade/custom%20separate.js&v=3.60.0) to this `property` / `issue`, I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks you so much, This is not working out of the box. They require add custom function for collider. https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body-customSeparateY ,